# How can I split long log with fluentd

Tags: kubernetes, logging, fluentd

I have some app that will output some very long log line(>1MB). And I want to collect the log with fluentd. Because of some limit in our storage side, each log line sent to the backend storage should be within 16KB.
How can I split the 1MB log line to several <16KB line with fluentd?
Plus can fluentd maintain the sequencial of such splitted line, in the following way:
origin log

```
11111111.....11111    #(30K * 1)
```

splitted log

```
[1/2]111111....1111   #(16K * 1)
[2/2]111111....1111   #(14K * 1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if fluentd has some plugin that does this out of the box. You may write your own plugin for this kind of splitting and sequencing. Or, you can write another component on the receiving end to do this before dumping to file.